# Reverse connection error

Tags: c#, dns, connection

I'm trying to make a reverse connection, but nothing happens
system only tries to connect infinitely

client code :

```
 private static Socket _clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    public static TcpClient client;
    private const int _PORT = 28562;  //port
   public static string connectTo = "example.ddns.net"; //addres
    public static IPAddress ipaddress = null;
```

...

```
private static void ConnectToServer()
        {

            int attempts = 0;

            bool IsValidIP = IPAddress.TryParse(connectTo, out ipaddress);
            if (IsValidIP == false)
            {
                ipaddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(connectTo)[0];
                Console.WriteLine(Dns.GetHostAddresses(connectTo)[0]);
            }
            client = new TcpClient();

            while (!_clientSocket.Connected)
            {
                try
                {
                    attempts++;
                    Console.WriteLine("Connection attempt " + attempts);
                    _clientSocket.Connect(ipaddress, _PORT);
                    Thread.Sleep(100);

                }
                catch (SocketException)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                }
            }
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected");

        }
```

What can I change to be able to connect?

Comment: What's a "reverse connection"?

Comment: Read my reasponse at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51469037/tcplistener-how-to-start-server-with-global-ip-address#comment89906673_51469037

Comment: @jdweng  This is not working for me. This does not solve my problem.

Comment: @jdweng Help me please

Comment: Looping forever will not open a connection.  If it fails the first time it will normally always fail. Does the server have a socket listening for port 28562 using TCP?  Check status of ports on both client and server from cmd.exe using >Netstat -a

Comment: TCP 0.0.0.0:28562   MyComputer-PC:0   LISTENING