# TcpListener - how to start server with global ip address

Tags: c#, server, tcplistener

I would start `TcpListener` server with my global IP address.
I have open ports and using DMZ and my port 8074 is available and i should be able to start this server.

My code looks like :

```
IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("XX.XXX.XX.XXX.XX");
TcpListener server = new TcpListener(ip, Convert.ToInt32(8888));
TcpClient client = default(TcpClient);
try
{
    server.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Server started...");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
};
```

And all the time i have Error looks like:

> Activated Event   Time    Duration    Thread Exception: An exception was
>   thrown: "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException" in System.dll ("The
>   requested address is different in this context"). An exception was
>   thrown: "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException" in System.dll ("The
>   requested address is different in this context") 5.52s [5780] Worker
>   thread

You can check if you want this port is accessible on my IP address but can't start server on this.

Comment: IPAddress.Parse takes a string and your argument isn't a string. Please post code that can, at least, compile.

Comment: You can only have one connection with the same three parameters 1) Source IP 2) Destination IP 3) Port number.  You should always use for listener IP.Any and not the PC IP. When you have both the client and server on same IP the 3 parameters are the same.  So using IP.Any allows both the client and server to be on same PC because on client you use the PC IP and the server you use IP.Any.

Comment: @HansKilian I edited code - and now is compilable. :) sorry it was mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah thanks @jdweng .
All i need to change was  just this lane :

```
IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Any;
```